# Sore 'str' and 'list' objects

Tags: python

I am new in python world but like to learn, so I wrote a little code, but it gives me this error.

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

Please explain to me what to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# import the server implementation
import subprocess
import time
from time import strftime
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

# Time and date variable
t_date = format(strftime('%Y%m%d'))
t_time = format(strftime('%H%M')) 

# READ VALUES
# choose the serial client
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600, stopbits=1, parity='N', bytesize=8, timeout=1)
client.connect()

ra = client.read_input_registers(0,44)
rb = client.read_input_registers(45,18)


with open("data.tmp", 'w', 1) as f:
data = ra.registers + rb.registers
f.write(str(data))
```

The results in DATA.TMP are this:

```
[1, 0, 710, 3287, 2, 0, 710, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 639, 4997, 2257, 3, 0, 639]
```

I would like to add date and time to it and get lost of the accolades[]
So I will get this :

```
20140926,1635,1, 0, 710, 3287, 2, 0, 710, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 639, 4997, 2257, 3, 0, 639
```

Can this be done simply?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `str(data)` use `', '.join(map(str,data))`. This will transform the list into a string:

```
>>> data = [1, 0, 710, 3287, 2, 0, 710, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 639, 4997, 2257, 3, 0, 639]
>>> ', '.join(map(str,data))
'1, 0, 710, 3287, 2, 0, 710, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 639, 4997, 2257, 3, 0, 639'
```

You can then add write it to `f` with whatever you want:

```
f.write('foo, bar, ' + ', '.join(map(str,data)))
```

(or add foo and bar to data and just `f.write(', '.join(map(str,data)))`)